# How to achieve the following layout with dynamic width in Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout with a simple card view with a text inside, and a text at the bottom. I want the card's width to be **at least** the width of the bottom text. So something like setting a minimum width.

I drew a picture illustrating what I want but wasn't able to implement it in Constraint Layout.

[image: layout]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Barriers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier) will do the magic for you!
With this feature you automatically get the width of the widest object in a certain scope.

From Android Documentaion:

> A Barrier references multiple widgets as input, and creates a virtual guideline based on the most extreme widget on the specified side. For example, a left barrier will align to the left of all the referenced views.

The following xml will check the widest width of the views `content_text` and `bottom_text`

```xml
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="content_text,bottom_text" />
```

Now you can use this barrier as a constrain in any other view (inside the same ConstraintLayout)

```xml
    <View
        android:id="@+id/card_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/content_text"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/content_text" />
```

That's what my result looks like:

**Sample 1**
[image: Sample 1 - Short content text]

**Sample 2**
[image: Sample 2 - Very long content text]

My complete XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/card_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/content_text"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/content_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"

        android:text="This is a very large content text. It is so long that it needs a second line"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a bottom text with a particular length"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_background" />


    <!-- Magic happens here -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="content_text,bottom_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this helps.
[Here could you read more about barriers](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html)

Comment: Awesome answer! It seems like this can't be achieved if the content_text was inside something like a CardView? The views all have to be siblings right?

Comment: Yes, this solution seems to work only with view siblings.
You can use @+id/content_text as a ghost view by setting visibility to invisible and inserting the same TextView (only different id and visibility set to visible) inside the cardview @+id/card_background

But I can not recommend that.

Comment: You could also write a custom layout and handle it programmatically. Take a look at this: https://guides.codepath.com/android/defining-custom-views